# How do I fix the segmentation fault error in my assembly code?

Tags: assembly, arm64

I am trying to reverse a 5 char string from the user and point it back, but the program simply prints the original string and "segmentation error".

```
.data // start of the data segment
input:
    .space 100
inputSize = .-input
prompt:
    .asciz "Enter a string with 5 characters"
promptSize = .-prompt
reversed:
    .space 100
reversedSize = .-reversed
.text // start o the text segment (Code)
.global _start // Linux Standard _start, similar to main in C/C++
_start:
// Display prompt message
mov x0, #0          // stdout
ldr x1, =prompt      // store the address of flow into x1
ldr x2, =promptSize      // store the size of the flowwWorld string into x2
mov x8, #64         // store 64 to x8, this is the linux write call
svc 0  
mov x0, #1 // file descriptor for stdin
ldr x1, =input      // store the address of flow into x1
ldr x2, =inputSize
mov x8, #63 // system call number for read
svc 0
mov x0, #1 // file descriptor for stdout
ldr x1, =input // address of input buffer
mov x2, #100 // maximum number of bytes to write
mov x8, #64 // system call number for write
svc 0
// Reverse the input string
mov x1, #0        // set x1 to 0 to represent the start of the input string
add x2, x2, #-2  // set x2 to the second-to-last index in the input string
mov x4, #0
loop: 
  cmp x4, #2
  b.gt end
  ldrb w3, [x1], #1  // load byte from input string starting from the left
  ldrb w4, [x2], #-1 // load byte from input string starting from the right
  strb w4, [x1, #-1] // store right byte at the left index
  strb w3, [x2, #1]  // store left byte at the right index
  add x4, x4, 1
  b loop             // jump to loop
end:
// Display the reversed string
mov x0, #0          // stdout
ldr x1, =input      // store the address of input into x1
ldr x2, =inputSize  // store the size of the input string into x2
mov x8, #64         // store 64 to x8, this is the linux write call
svc 0
// Exit to the OS, essentially this code does this in c
// return 0;
mov x0, #0          // return value
mov x8, #93         // Service call code
svc 0
```

to reverse the string, i tried swapping the outer two character and then the inner two characters, leaving the middle one where it is.

heres a pic of the registers after i used ddd debug: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZejG.jpg)

Comment: @pm100 - this is AArch64, 64-bit ARM code, so [arm64] is the right tag.   We can tell because of the `x` and `w` registers like `x0` and `w3`, instead of `r0` and so on.

Comment: When you run it under a debugger (like GDB for example), which instruction segfaults?  What are the register values when that happens?   (See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for some GDB tips, like `layout reg`).  I assume you are building this into a static executable on a Linux system, like `gcc -nostdlib -static hello.S`, or with `as` and `ld` manually.

Comment: You seem to be treating `x1` and `x2` as pointers to your buffers - but `x1` is initialized to zero, and `x2` is two less than an uninitialized value, so no telling where it's pointing.

Comment: oh i wanted x1 to be initialized to the starting char of the string and x2 to the end; how would i fix this?

Comment: By loading the address, like you're doing in multiple other places, e.g. `ldr x1, =input`

Comment: Now is a great time to learn how to use your debugger. In the debugger, it says that the problem occurred at `pc = 0x400100 <loop+8>`. What instruction is at `0x400100`? Oh, it's the `ldrb w3, [x1], #1`. What does that instruction do? It loads a byte from `x1` (and then increments x1). What is `x1`? The debugger says that it is `0`.